# Why does Ohrmazd need to plan a time to fight Ahriman?

Tags: persian

In the Bundahishn, Ohrmazd, after being confronted with Ahriman, decides to set a concrete time to fight Ahriman and resolve the conflict:

> Then Ohrmazd, through omniscience, knew that: If I do not grant a period of contest, then it will be possible for him to act so that he may be able to cause the seduction of my creatures to himself. As even now there are many of the intermixture of mankind who practice wrong more than right. And Ohrmazd spoke to the evil spirit thus: 'Appoint a period! so that the intermingling of the conflict may be for nine thousand years. For he knew that by appointing this period the evil spirit would be undone.

([The Bundahishn](http://www.avesta.org/mp/bundahis.html)).

After reading this passage several times, I don't understand why "by appointing this period the evil spirit would be undone." Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the context Ohrmazd knows his creatures can be corrupted and that in this way he tricks the evil spirit into accepting a proposed time for their final fight (making sure they are not fighting constantly). Ohrmazd, using his omniscience knew the end result would result in the evil spirit being disabled.

> And the evil spirit shouted thus: 'I will not depart, I will not provide assistance for thy creatures, I will not offer praise among thy creatures, and I am not of the same opinion with thee as to good things. I will destroy thy creatures for ever and everlasting; moreover, I will force all thy creatures into disaffection to thee and affection for myself.'  And the explanation thereof is this, that the evil spirit reflected in this manner, that Ohrmazd was helpless as regarded him, therefore He proffers peace; and he did not agree, but bore on even into conflict with Him.
>
> And Ohrmazd spoke thus: 'You are not omniscient and almighty, O evil spirit! so that it is not possible for thee to destroy me, and it is not possible for thee to force my creatures so that they will not return to my possession.'
> Then the evil spirit, **unobservant and through ignorance**, was content
> with that agreement; just like two men quarreling together, who
> propose a time thus: Let us appoint such-and-such a day for a fight.
>
> Ohrmazd also knew this, through omniscience, that within these nine
> thousand years, for three thousand years everything proceeds by the
> will of Ohrmazd, three thousand years there is an intermingling of the
> wills of Ohrmazd and Ahriman, and the last three thousand years the
> evil spirit is disabled, and they keep the adversary away from the
> creatures.

It might even be because Ohrmazd is convinced that by then he will have made sure Ahriman is not feared anymore by his creations.